What are the strongest arguments against the view that all of philosophy is about "bets" or subjective judgment calls?
My question is motivated by this answer to Are there objective standards proposed in the literature for estimating the likelihood of a hypothesis when empirical statistics are unavailable?, in particular this comment under said answer:

it’s more of a definitional paper rather than anything, and contrasts between the viewpoint that two people can be both rational with respect to the same evidence, or one is rational and the other not. Ultimately, from an epistemic standpoint, I lean a little more towards almost all of philosophy being judgement calls. I think of them as bets. But you can make a bet by flipping a coin or you can make a bet by gathering as much information as possible.

Two questions:

Does this view have an official name in philosophy?
What are the strongest arguments against this view?


Dutch book arguments cover how one can connect subjective credences of belief (usually represented as probabilities) to betting dispositions. However, this has more to do with arguing about how one should structure these credences, rather than making the general argument that philosophy comes down to subjective judgment calls. I’m not sure if there’s a term for the latter. However, I am guessing one can connect binary beliefs (I.e. all or nothing beliefs) to all or nothing bets similar to how it is done for credence (degrees of belief).

It could be said that Husserl’s pairing in the ever-expanding horizon of intersubjective possibilities of the lifeworld after the famous epoche style bracketing of the natural attitude to arrive at the coherence of expectations fixes the landscape and argues against arbitrary or idiosyncratic subjective judgment calls, even applicable for subjective idealists or bayesians…

@DoubleKnot can’t you have subjective judgment calls even if there was only one, correct doxastic attitude to take? For example, the correct doxastic attitude to take with regards to the earth might be that it is a sphere, but both flat earth and global earth believers can be making “bets” with respect to their positions, without these judgments being completely arbitrary.

The view is called radical skepticism or global relativism, radical/global because applied to all domains and claims. In this naive form, it is self-defeating when applied to itself. Variants of it are also main objections to more sophisticated forms of relativism, responses and rebuttals are surveyed in SEP, Relativism:"The strongest and most persistent charge leveled against all types of relativism, but (global) alethic relativism in particular, is the accusation of self-refutation."

@Conifold per your article, ” Traditionally, relativism is contrasted with: Absolutism, the view that at least some truths or values in the relevant domain apply to all times, places or social and cultural frameworks.” But you can view, for example, truth as absolute while still thinking that beliefs in philosophy can be represented as judgment calls. So this doesn’t seem to be accurate.

Something is a judgement call if I don't know the answer but must take action or a position anyway. Yet, there is still a right answer, I simply have to see how things will turn out. The best approach is to wait until the answer is clear, or until the cost of not deciding exceeds the cost of being wrong. If possible. When I was in college, I asked my prof how we can tell the truth from a false proposition. He said, "Truth is true and a false proposition is false." But how can we tell in advance? "We can't." That was the last Philosophy course I took. I can do 'wrong' all by myself.

@ScottRowe: done properly, in my opinion  philosophy is more about understanding the implications of any proposition then about establishing its truth or falsehood. That's the next step, applying the logical structure you have built to the real world and seeing if it is a successful model or not. If it isn't, then something is clearly false and needs further work or to be abandoned in favor of a model which is more successful. If it doesn't conflict with reality, then it can provisionally be considered true until you find a case that it doesn't handle, then see above. Algebra, not arithmetic.

@Syed of course everyone seemingly has and is entitled to their own subjective judgement calls which are usually coherent in the here-and-now local expectations such as your example, but not on the intersubjective Husserlian ever-expanding horizon of lived lifeworld as the condition of possibilities after the transcendental reduction. The 'in' is actually 'through', while the 'on' is really 'onto' the 'logos'...

@Syed If it were indeed as you suggested, then you're contradicting the universal claim in your own answer and you'd better delve into your concerned fallibilism which seems more coherent and non-circular on that Husserlian horizon than some universal thesis or theory...

@DoubleKnot can you repeat that but in English? (I.e. concisely and in a less convoluted fashion)

@keshlam yeah, I'm sure you have a better view of it than I do. I'm just impatient. Or, I was in college, Lo, these many years ago. Your approach sounds like new program development, something I have some experience with.
